# How to disable the output of a field depending on the return from another field?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

There are fields in my view that I would rather hide depending on the value of another field. I am lookinf for ways to do it in code, or otherwise but without enabling php filter.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which version of Views you use. I can't quite remember whether output rewriting was available in V2, but I suppose it was. In V3, it's there, waiting for you to use it.

Output rewriting accepts any HTML code and you can use replacements from what the query returned. I'm not sure you can use PHP there, perhaps you can, but I've never really tried. Anyways, let's say you have `field_foo` and `field_bar`, and that both are some select options or checkboxes or some other multiple choice thing, having key-value pairs in the database (like 1|foo, 2|bar etc.).

In this situation, you should have four options available:

```
[field_foo_value]
[field_foo_value_raw]
[field_bar_value]
[field_bar_value_raw]
```

(they'll probably be named a bit differently, I can't quite remember the exact naming convention). You can rewrite the "bar" field output like this:

```
<span class="visibility-[field_foo_value_raw]">[field_bar_value]</span>
```

Then, assuming the possible keys for "foo" are 1 and 2, you can write some CSS:

```
span.visibility-1 { display: inline; }
span.visibility-2 { display: none; }
```

If PHP is allowed, it should be even easier, but I have a feeling you can only use HTML. Anyway, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`hook_form_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) or [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/6) you can alter the `views_exposed_form` form. From there, [it should be possible](http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/using-ctools-form-item-dependency-visibility) to use [CTools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools)' Dependent to set visibility dependencies between fields. Views's exposed form layout is partially handled in the theme layer (see [views-exposed-form.tpl.php](http://views.doc.logrus.com/views-exposed-form_8tpl_8php-source.html)) so more work is probably needed to hide/show the labels.

Comment: I'm not trying to do anything with exposed filters. But since you have mentioned, forms should be dealt with in the module level, leaving only theming to the theme level :)

Comment: If your are not messing with the views_exposed_form, then CTools' Dependent should be straightforward to use ;).

Answer (score 0):

This module seams like it would do what you need. I've used it and it's easy to setup and quick to use.

http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields